# meson: ::1 generates DEPRECATION: ":" is not allowed in test name, it has been replaced with "_"

Tags: string, testing, meson-build

I have a meson test which tests ping to `::1`

```
args = ['-c 1', '::1']
name = 'ping ' + ' '.join(args) # 'ping -c1 ::1'
test(name, ping, args : args)
```

`meson test` generates:

```
meson.build:94: DEPRECATION: ":" is not allowed in test name "ping -c::1", it has been replaced with "_"
...
1/1 ping -c1 __1            OK             0.02s
```

But I'd really like to print command which command is being issued, because even `meson test -v` does not print the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you have meson version >= 0.56 since this check/deprecation is a result of [this commit](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/commit/55cf399ff8b9c15300f26dd1a46045dda7d49f98) that adds [support of running subproject tests](https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-56-0.html#meson-test-can-now-filter-tests-by-subproject) using syntax with ':' that delimits subproject's name from test name, e.g.:

```
meson test subprojectname:testname
```

and thus, apparently, it must be replaced to avoid misinterpretation of part of name as non-existing subproject (so you see just warning about this and it's replaced with '_').

That commit also has specific reasoning about ':'

> ```
> Also forbid ':' in test names. We already forbid this elsewhere, so
> should not be a big deal.
> ```

So, your option is always keep meson below 0.56 (I checked your code on my 0.49 and it works) which is, apparently, not good, or adapt your test name:

```
test('test_ping_loopback', ping, args : args)
```

Comment: Thanks for info! Keeping old version is no-go, because this should be part of docker testing , as it's a system tool, we try to support both various old and new meson versions (travis: https://travis-ci.org/github/iputils/iputils/branches, going to switch to github actions due pull rate limit). But having a limitation like this is another reason for me not considering Meson as a good build system. I might report a bug about this limitation.

Comment: @pevik quite reasonable limitation though, ability to run tests in subprojects would need, say, for 30% of users, having colon in tests, say, for 0.01% -> design is always a trade-off.